# How to assign a security group to the perticular user in OpenERP 7

Tags: openerp-7

In my custom module the security kind of directory and its related groups is working fine.

Then after I was created a many users for that groups.

**I want from the Following things:**

1. As a  Admin, I need to give separate access rights.
2. As a  Users, I need to give separate access rights.

In some Module

I have achieved from the front-end using groups in OpenERP 7

Is there any method to do from back-end ?

Comment: Even in back-end you need to do it using groups. So, try to create security rules to your models. For specific rules you can specify group as  *base.group_erp_manager* (administration/access rights group).